# Suggested edits review is done poorly

Tags: discussion, review

Can our site do something like SO review validation?
I'm referring to edit made by anonymous to this post:

[Transit via uk with Italian Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/transit-via-uk-with-italian-schengen-visa/19435#19435)

@AliAwan, @Olielo, how do you review the edits? What's wrong with you? How can you approve things like this? And this is not the first time! Personally I can't find any rejected edit from @Olielo at all. Can we do something with this?

Answer (score 5):

I see your point. Some edits are controversial and can be seen either way and some are actively harmful, such as the one you spotted. The problem with review validation on SO as I recall it, is that the *tests* you get are a fairly random sample of previous reviews and you end up being blocked from reviewing for deciding *wrongly* on the controversial ones.

My suggestion in this particular case is to mod flag the post in question and point out the unacceptable review behaviour to our site moderators who may deal with this by contacting the reviewers in question privately. Public shaming on Meta, where they most likely are not seeing this post is somewhat rude IMHO. Whenever I call out a particular users behaviour on meta or chat I try to not name them AND to notify them of my post in a way they can see, up to commenting on older unrelated posts of them with a link.